# PostgREST on Google Cloud SQL: unix socket URI format?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, unix-socket, postgrest

Any of you with experience with PostgREST and Cloud SQL ?

I have my SQL instance ready with open access (0.0.0.0/0) and I can access it with local PostGREST using the Cloud proxy app.

Now I want to run Postgrest from an instance of the same project but
I can't find an URI format for Postgrest that supports Cloud SQL format, as 
Google SQL Cloud uses only unix sockets like `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`

**Config 1**

```
db-uri = "postgres://postgres:password@/unix(/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME)/mydatabase"
db-schema = "api"
jwt-secret = "OOcJ7VoSY1mXqod4MKtb9WCCwt9erJkRQ2tzYmLb4Xe="
db-anon-role = "web_anon"
server-port=3000
```

Returns `{"details":"could not translate host name \"unix(\" to address: Unknown host\n","code":"","message":"Database connection error"}`

**Config 2**

```
db-uri = "postgres://postgres:password@/mydatabase?unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
db-schema = "api"
jwt-secret = "OOcJ7VoSY1mXqod4MKtb9WCCwt9erJkRQ2tzYmLb4Xe="
db-anon-role = "web_anon"
server-port=3000
```

The parser rejects the  question mark 
`{"details":"invalid URI query parameter: \"unix_socket\"\n","code":"","message":"Database connection error"}`

**Config 3**

```
db-uri = "postgres://postgres:password@/mydatabase"
db-schema = "api"
jwt-secret = "OOcJ7VoSY1mXqod4MKtb9WCCwt9erJkRQ2tzYmLb4Xe="
db-anon-role = "web_anon"
server-port=3000
server-unix-socket= "/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
```

`server-unix-socket` appears to only take socket lock file path. Feeding it `/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` tries to delete file as in `postgrest.exe: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: DeleteFile "/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME": invalid argument                                                                t (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)

#### Documentation

Cloud SQL Doc

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

PostgREST

- http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/configuration.html
- https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1186
- https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/169

**Environment**

- PostgreSQL version:11
- PostgREST version: 6.0.2
- Operating system: Win10 and Alpine

Comment: Did you tried:`postgres//<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_sock=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432`, or maybe `host` instead of `unix_sock`

Comment: Try it like: `db-uri = postgres:///user@/dbname`(no password). Also, [server-unix-socket](http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/configuration.html#server-unix-socket) is only a webserver setting, not a pg connection setting.

I suggest trying the connection string with `psql <db-uri>` first. If the db-uri is right, it will also work with PostgREST.

Comment: did you get this working @j-dumont? I tried steve chavez approach, but that defaults to `/var/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` but I can't find a way to customise the socket location as the location is hardcoded by cloudrun.

Answer (score 4):

First you have to add the Cloud SQL connection to the Cloud Run instance:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#configuring

After that, the DB connection will be available in the service on a Unix domain socket at path `/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_connection_name>` and you can set the `PGRST_DB_URI` environment variable to reflect that.

Here's the correct format:
`postgres://<pg_user>:<pg_pass>@/<db_name>?host=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_connection_name>`

e.g.
`postgres://postgres:postgres@/postgres?host=/cloudsql/project-id:zone-id-1:sql-instance`

Comment: I think that would double the costs

Comment: @confiq Why is that?

Comment: I think it was little misunderstanding, I thought that your solution is to run external cloud run instance that will do the proxy! 
Folder `/cloudsql` is generated in cloud run and cloud function so no need to add instances! 

My fault!

Answer (score 2):

According with [Connecting with CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connecting_to), the example is:

`# postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix`_sock=/cloudsql//.s.PGSQL.5432

Then you can try with (Just as @marian.vladoi mentioned):

```
db-uri = "postgres://postgres:password@/mydatabase?unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Keep in mind that the connection name should include:

```
ProjectID:Region:DatabaseName
```

For example: `myproject:myregion:myinstance`

Anyway, you can find here more options to [connect from external applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/external-connection-methods) and [from within Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app).

Comment: Bro thanks! it works for me. Take in account that if password contains special caracters you need to scape https://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried many variations but couldn't get it to work out of the box, however I'll post this workaround.

FWIW I was able to use an alternate socket location with postgrest locally, but then when trying to use the cloudsql location it doesn't seem to interpret it right - perhaps the colons in the socket path are throwing it off?

In any case as @Steve_Chávez mentions, this approach does work `db-uri = postgres:///user:password@/dbname` and defaults to the postgrest default socket location (`/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`). So in the docker entrypoint we can symlink this location to the actual socket injected by Cloud Run.

First, add the following to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/blob/d4aba5cb08d4373eca92ceed5e583c984fd01cf0/docker/Dockerfile#L45) (above `USER 1000`):

```
RUN mkdir -p /run/postgresql/ && chown postgrest:postgrest /run/postgresql/
```

Then add an executable file at `/etc/entrypoint.bash` containing:

```
set -eEux pipefail

CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_NAME=${CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_NAME:-PROJECT_REGION_INSTANCE_NAME}
POSTGRES_SOCKET_LOCATION=/run/postgresql

ln -s /cloudsql/${CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_NAME}/.s.PGSQL.5432 ${POSTGRES_SOCKET_LOCATION}/.s.PGSQL.5432 
postgrest /etc/postgrest.conf
```

Change the Dockefile entrypoint to `CMD /etc/entrypoint.sh`. Then add `CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_NAME` as an env var in cloud run. The `PGRST_DB_URI` env var is like so `postgres://authenticator:password@/postgres`

An alternative approach if you don't like this, would be to connect via [serverless vpc connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access).

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too.

I end up doing a one-liner for DB-URI env variable

```
host=/cloudsql/project-id:zone:instance-id user=user port=5432 dbname=dbname password=password
```

However, I have postgrest running on cloud run that lets you specify the instance connection name via

INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=/cloudsql/project-id:zone:instance-id

Maybe you can host it there and you end up doing it serverless Im not sure where are you running it currently.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run